# Apache Reverse Proxy MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache, reverse-proxy

I have mongodb installed on Windows in an ip address `10.21.10.11:27017`. When I am in the same network, I am able to connect to `mongodb with the URL mongodb://10.21.10.11`. However, I would like to access it from outside. For this, I need to do reverse proxy on Apache. What is the correct command to redirect?
My attempts are like this

```
ProxyPass /MongoDB http://10.21.10.11:27017
ProxyPassReverse /MongoDB http://10.21.10.11:27017
```

But, it is not redirecting there.

I have also tried

```
  ProxyPass /MongoDB mongodb://10.21.10.11:27017
  ProxyPassReverse /MongoDB mongodb://10.21.10.11:27017
```

But it did not work. I have seen that a few people reported that it works well for nginx. Please post your answer, if anyone configured it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not speak HTTP. It used to a long time ago but not anymore. Therefore you cannot front it with an HTTP reverse proxy.

Comment: Can we redirect through TCP then? I would like to access the DB from an outside network. The DB is accessible within the local network.

Comment: You can proxy standalone and mongos nodes through tcp.

Comment: Thank you. I have made a backend server connected to mongodb locally and made that backend server reverse proxy to connect outside